# How to move to a different team within the same company as a recent hire

Tags: professionalism, new-hires

I have been in my current role for 4 months, and I want to move to a different team because the career track my manager has laid out and discussed with me does not work with my career goals and aspirations.

There was some confusion before I joined my team, and I was told that I would be in a different position/track than the one I ended up being in (my manager agrees that there was confusion around the position I was coming in to).

What can I do if I don't want to waste a year of my life in this position, but also don't want to lose relationships (I don't hate my work or my coworkers, and my manager has been great about listening to and implementing my suggestions, however the work I am doing is only half of what I thought I would be doing when I joined).

Comment: If the manager is so good at hearing your concerns then its your job to voice those concerns.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere what's the graceful way of navigating a situation where someone is a new hire, and wants to go to another team because of the reasons stated, but also doesn't want to burn bridges and lose relationships. I'll add that to my op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your options are:

1. Discuss this with your manager - he might be able to transfer you to another department or another position.
2. Look on the companies internal job site (if one is present) and apply for jobs in the department that you are interested in.
3. Go to HR. They might be able to move you.

Those are your in-company options. You can always go find a new job *outside of your current company*.

Comment: I would advise talking to your manager about options 2 and 3 before pursuing them. If you pursue them without talking to him, you risk endangering that relationship.

Comment: Also, some companies have policies that don't allow you to move internally until after a period of time (typically 1 year in your current role).